# Ubuntu 17.10 logging out

Tags: 17.10

I'm a relatively new Ubuntu/Linux user.

For some reason I keep being logged out when I open Chrome/Chromium/Firefox from the dash to panel extension. This also happens when my screen times out.

I can't seem to find anything online, has anyone else experienced this or know why it might be happening?